# Is it possible to make distro.exe by "wsl --import"?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I imported a wsl backup file made through `wsl --export` from another machine through `wsl --import`.

But unlike when I installed WSL Ubuntu on the Window Store, `distro.exe` file such as `ubuntu.exe`(found on Start Menu) was not created. Because of this, there is a problem getting WSL support from JetBrain IDE. This is beacause JetBrain IDE recognizes the path to WSL through the `distro.exe` file.

If anyone has solved this problem, I'd like to get some help. Thank you for reading it.

Editted: Windows is v.1909(OS build 18363.592), and I tried to https://winaero.com/blog/export-import-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/

Comment: The distribution can be run using `wsl.exe --distribution <Distro Name>` command. See `wsl.exe --help` for more information.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thank you for your reply. But I'm using an imported WSL (for example, I'm also using it as an alternative to cmd and Powershell by adding it to the right click context menu). The problem is that JetBrain IDE uses `distro.exe` files such as `ubuntu.exe` and `kali.exe` to refer to WSL.

That's why I wonder if `wsl --import` allows me to create a `distro.exe` file just like the Windows Store Linux Distro Installation.

Comment: Which Jetbrains IDE are you using here? There are [many](https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html) of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.(Windows 10 build 18363.592)

#### 1. Export your WSL distro

`wsl --export {your_distribution_name} rootfs.tar.gz` to export your wsl distro. (your distro would be saved into tarball.)

#### 2. Install your distro via Distro-Launcher

I used [Yuk7's version](https://github.com/yuk7/wsldl). First of all, Download Launcher.exe, and rename it `your_distro_name.exe` then make directory to position WSL distro. Put `your_distro_name.exe` and `rootfs.tar.gz` in there.

Now you can install distro just run `your_distro_name.exe`. after installation, you could run your distro in powershell. `PS > your_distro_name`

#### 3. Settig wsl.distributions.xml

`C:\users\\{user_name}\\.{jetbrains_ide_name_version}\config\options\wsl.distributions.xml`

Jetbrains IDE supports WSL via `wsl.distributions.xml`, you should add your `distro.exe` into this to use WSL on Jetbrains IDE.

```xml
<application>
  <component name="WslDistributionsService" version="1">
    <descriptors>
      <set>
        <descriptor>
          <id>DEBIAN</id>
          <microsoft-id>Debian</microsoft-id>
          <executable-path>debian.exe</executable-path>
          <presentable-name>Debian GNU/Linux</presentable-name>
        </descriptor>
        <descriptor>
          <id>KALI</id>
          <microsoft-id>kali-linux</microsoft-id>
          <executable-path>kali.exe</executable-path>
          <presentable-name>Kali Linux</presentable-name>
        </descriptor>
        ...
      </set>
    </descriptors>
  </component>
</application>
```

```xml
<!-- DESCRIPTOR FOR YOUR DISTRO -->
<descriptor>
  <id>YOUR_DISTRO_NAME</id>
  <microsoft-id>Your-distro-name</microsoft-id>
  <executable-path>your_distro_name.exe</executable-path>
  <presentable-name>your_distro_name</presentable-name>
</descriptor>
```

Just add `<descriptor>` into `<set>`.

#### 4. Restart Your JetBrains IDE

Finally, I could use my exported wsl distro in another machine's WebStorm :)

Comment: I'm having issues with the last step. My config file was under AppData/Roaming and it doesn't seem to be added after I change the files.

Comment: Manged to get it working by adding the full path to the exe. but now I get an "credentials are not valid for this WSL distribution" error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the latest solution seems not working anymore, at least for me and at 03/2021. Maybe Phpstorm doesn't use the xml anymore and it query the registry (and it's better don't mess with the registry in this case in my opinion)
I would like to share with you how I get it to work (not only the wsl$ path but also php and git executables in phpstorm).

- Follow the instructions above until point 2: the distro is installed and in the same directory has been created the file `ext4.vhdx` containing the vm disk. Check it with `wsl -l -v`
- Install your distro of choice from the Microsoft Store, with the same version of your imported distro.
- Run the new distro one time, then turn off it `wsl --shutdown <YOUR_DISTRO_NAME>`
- go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.<YOUR_DISTRO_NAME>\LocalState` and rename `ext4.vhdx` to `ext4.vhdx.old` (just for security, later you can delete it)
- copy the previously generated `ext4.vhdx` in the above LocalState path
- Set the new distro as default with `wsl --set-default <YOUR_DISTRO_NAME>`
- unregister the previously imported distro `wsl --unregister <IMPORTED_DISTRO>`

Now the new installation from the store will use your imported vhdx disk. You can delete `ext4.vhdx.old`.

In my case now all is working nice and smooth :)